# A piece of C code, that probably does something with memory

Tags: c, function, pointers

I stepped on the following piece of code a couple days ago and I am not sure what does it do exactly.

```
int (*func) ();
func = (int (*) () ) some_array_here;
(int) (*func) ();
```

The first line looks like an integer pointer but the ()s bug me. The second line looks like a cast and the third line, i don't really know. Can you guys help? Thanks

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html

Comment: Most C code does something with memory...  And in this case, the code is making a function call, which does do something with memory on most machines (and on every machine in existence today, if you count registers as memory).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first line declares a function pointer.  The second line casts `some_array_here` to a function pointer.  The third line invokes a function call through that pointer.

My guess is that the context is some sort of shell-coding example (i.e. executing user-injected code).  You should never do this in real life.

Comment: And all but maybe the first would make me very sad when I saw them in production code :)

Comment: Yes it is indeed a shell-code example, but I thought this was a piece of code that had a general use. So is this some short of a trick?

And also shouldn't we invoke the function with something like func()? Or there is a different theory when invoking pointer functions?

Comment: @Crone: If `foo` is a function or a function-pointer, then you can invoke a function-call with either `(*foo)()` or `foo()`, they're identical.

Comment: @Crone: And no, the above never has a practical use (not one that I can think of, anyway); it's completely undefined behaviour (consider that on a [Harvard architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture), it would be impossible!).

Answer (score 1):

In first line func is pointer to function whose return type is `int`.

2nd line casts `some_array_here` to function pointer.

3rd line is function call using `func` pointer.

Refer to this: http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html